# How to bring the Tiger Census Reporter API to GeoPandas

Tags: census, geopandas

I'm trying to read the Tiger2016 API (from Census Reporter) into Geopandas. I'm not quite sure how to import the geometry. I'm assuming I need to convert the geometry lists into something geopandas can read.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import requests
from shapely.geometry import Point

def get_geography(geoid):

    api_url = 'https://api.censusreporter.org/1.0/geo/tiger2016/{0}?geom=true'
    r = requests.get(api_url.format(geoid))
    geo = r.json()

    #print(geo)
    land_area = geo['properties']['aland'] / 2589988  #
    pop = geo['properties']['population']
    pop_density = population / land_area
    #print(geoid, land_area, population)

    df =  pd.DataFrame({
                        'GeoId': geoid,
                        'LandArea':land_area,
                        'Population': population,
                        'PopulationDensity': pop_density,
                        'geometry' : geo['geometry']
                         })

    #df['geometry'] = Point(df['geometry'])
    #return df 
    crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
    gpdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs, geometry= df.geometry)
    return gpdf

get_geography('86000US54901')
-> TypeError: must be real number, not list
```

df.geometry look like:  coordinates    [[[[-88.482952, 44.089387], [-88.481774, 44.08924], [-88.481035, 44.090236],

Answer (score 2):

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

def get_geography(geoid):
    # https://api.censusreporter.org/1.0/geo/tiger2016/16000US5367000?geom=true

    api_url = 'https://api.censusreporter.org/1.0/geo/tiger2016/{0}?geom=true'
    data = requests.get(api_url.format(geoid)).json()


    # Get Features
    fdf = pd.DataFrame({
                        'Geoid': geoid,
                        'LandArea': data['properties']['aland'] / 2589988,
                        'Population': data['properties']['population']
                        }, index=[0])
    fdf['PopulationDensity'] = fdf.Population / fdf.LandArea

    # Convert Points into Geopandas Geometry
    numpy_points =   np.array(data['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    fdf['Geometry'] = Polygon(numpy_points)

    return gpd.GeoDataFrame(fdf, crs='epsg:4326', geometry = 'Geometry')

get_geography_gpd2('86000US78666').plot()
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer using the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

The URL portion 'tiger2016' can age out, and must be replaced by the version that is currently supported, or 'latest'.  See the documentation: https://github.com/censusreporter/census-api/blob/master/API.md

```
api_url = 'https://api.censusreporter.org/1.0/geo/tiger2020/{0}?geom=true'
```